# I2C pull-up resistor: using an external one along with the internal

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, pic18

I'm implementing an I2C connection between a PIC18F4550 and an external eeprom memory. I know that an internal pull up resistor won't work, and that's why I am going to use an external one. However, I am using in the same port the last 4 pins to interface with a matrix keypad, and for that I have to enable the internal pull-ups for the whole port(this microcontroller doesn't offer the option to enable just for the ones you wnat). Will the internal pull-up affect in any way the connection even though I'm using an external resistor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will create a parallel connection of the internal and the external pull-up resistor. Taking into account weak pull-up current stated in controller's datasheet, the internal one is between 12-100 kOhms.

Generally the result depends on the value of the external resistor, calculate it for the chosen value and and both edge cases of the internal one, here's some info on the I2C resistor vs speed:
http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva689/slva689.pdf (consider the one described as the parallel connection of the two aforementioned)

From my experience: it shouldn't be a big problem, if you choose a rather small value external resistor. Generally less that 2kOhms vs 100kOhms might be simply considered 2000kOhms. This rounding is of course less true for 12kOhms.

The more general rule is: the bigger the resulting resistor is, the smaller currents flow, resulting in slower parasitic capacitance being recharged and thus limiting the connection speed. If you'd like to acquire some more knowledge on that, google for RC circuit impulse/step response, low pass passive RC filter and related topics.

Good luck with your design!

Comment: Would be possible for me to measure the resulting resistance with a voltage division circuit? If yes, then I should just find the external pull-up resistor that makes the resulting resistante about 2kOhms, shouldn't I?

Comment: I'd say that shorting the pulled-up pin to ground through an ammeter and measuring the current would be enough. Besides, keep in mind parameters like thermal drift, drift over time, extermal resistor tolerance etc. I don't know if you're just a hobbyist or a professional designer/you're just playing around with PIC or designing something commercial. If it's the first case, I'd just simple use any resistor ca. 2.2kOhm from the valid range and don't care as long as it works.

Comment: I'm doing this as a school project at the technical high school I study. For now there's no commercial purpose.

Comment: Consult your teacher/supervisor on the requirements then and post you further questions when you know your needs.

Comment: Just to let you know, I have tested the circuit with just using a 2.2K resistor and it worked.